# Multi-Select ListBox Binding Issue

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox, wpf-controls

I have created a custom control derived from a ListBox and I am having issues getting the "SelectedItemsList" to bind to it's corresponding property in the view model.

The problem:  The selected items in the list box do not make it into the property it is bound to in the view model.  The list box allows multiple selections but none of these make into the List in the view model.

MultiSelectListBox:

```
public class MultiSelectListBox : ListBox
{
    public MultiSelectListBox() { }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedItemsListProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "SelectedItemsList", 
            typeof(IList), 
            typeof(MultiSelectListBox),
            new PropertyMetadata(default(IList)));
    public IList SelectedItemsList
    {
        get { return (IList) GetValue(SelectedItemsListProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SelectedItemsListProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

declaration in MainWindow.xaml:

```
<local:MultiSelectListBox
    DataContext="{StaticResource viewModel}"
    DockPanel.Dock="Left"
    Visibility="{Binding IsThailandFinal, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisConverter}, FallbackValue=Visible}"
    ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedOutputtapeList}"
    SelectionMode="Multiple"
    SelectedItemsList="{Binding SelectedOutputTapes, Mode=TwoWay}"
    HorizontalAlignment="Right"
    Background="DeepSkyBlue"
    Foreground="MidnightBlue"
    ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
    Height="100"
    Width="70"
    Margin="5"/>
```

View Model (simplified):

```
public class BTLogFrontEndViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private List<string> selectedOutputTapes;
    public BTLogFrontEndViewModel()
    {
        selectedOutputTapes = new List<string>();
    }
    public List<string> SelectedOutputTapes
    {
        get
        {
            return selectedOutputTapes;
        }
        set
        {
            selectedOutputTapes = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedOutputTapes");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Post code for your ObservableCollection and do you see any binding error in output window of Visual Studio?

Comment: ObservableCollection is a .NET collection, no code to show.

Comment: I meant declaration of `SelectedOutputTapes`, not source code of ObservableCollection. Also, what do you mean by `I am having issues`? Can you be more precise regarding problem statement?

Comment: Rohit, I have updated my question with more detail.  Thanks for helping so far, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to not use a custom ListBox and use objects in your list that extend INotifyPropertyChanged:

```
<ListBox
    Width="70"
    Height="100"
    HorizontalAlignment="Right"
    Margin="5"
    Background="DeepSkyBlue"
    DockPanel.Dock="Left"
    Foreground="MidnightBlue"
    ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedOutputtapeList}"
    ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
    SelectionMode="Multiple"
    DisplayMemberPath="Description"
    Visibility="{Binding IsThailandFinal, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisConverter}, FallbackValue=Visible}">
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
            <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding Path=IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>
```

Assuming BTLogFrontEndViewModel is your DataContext:

```
public class BTLogFrontEndViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private ObservableCollection<OutputTapeViewModel> m_SelectedOutputtapeList;

    public ObservableCollection<OutputTapeViewModel> SelectedOutputtapeList
    {
        get
        {
            return m_SelectedOutputtapeList;
        }
        set
        {
           m_SelectedOutputtapeList = value;

           NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedOutputtapeList");
        }
    }
}
```

Where OutputTapeViewModel is declared like:

```
public class OutputTapeViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private string m_Description;

    public string Description
    {
        get
        {
            return m_Description;
        }
        set
        {
            m_Description = value;

            NotifyPropertyChanged("Description");
        }
    }

    private bool m_IsSelected;

    public string IsSelected
    {
        get
        {
            return m_IsSelected;
        }
        set
        {
            m_IsSelected = value;

            NotifyPropertyChanged("IsSelected");
        }
    }
}
```

Important things to note is on the listbox I have added the DisplayMemberPath property for use of the description field in the OutputTapeViewModel class for what to show on the listbox. Also it has an item container style, which binds to the OutputTapeViewModel.IsSelected property when  selected in the ListBox. This OutputTapeViewModel.IsSelected allows you to use the BTLogFrontEndViewModel.SelectedOutputtapeList property in such ways as:

```
var selectedItems = SelectedOutputtapeList.Where(item => item.IsSelected);
```

This only works in your case if you don't care about the overhead of doing the LINQ expression.